# calendar, first date wrong

Tags: calendar, date-format, events

i've got a weird issue with the first date from calendar entries showing up as the wrong day number **and** weekday. ie: instead of **01 Sunday** it reads **001 Monday**, but every other entry loads perfectly.

full code:

```
{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="5057" date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" pad_short_weeks="n" show_months="1"}
{display_each_month}
    {display_each_day}
        {if day_event_total > 0}<strong>{date format="%d %l"}</strong>{/if}
        {events}
            {event_start_date format="%g:%i %a"}<br />
            {title}<br />
        {/events}
    {/display_each_day}
{/display_each_month}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

you can see it working [here](http://fryemuseum.org/calendar/newsletter/2014/03/) (with some additional inline formatting), in the right column under **March Calendar**

---

**Update:** to confuse things more, there is [another monthly calendar](http://fryemuseum.org/calendar/month_list/2014/03/) on the site, from which i created the template above, which does not commit the same error. both have the same settings for PHP handling and use the exact same tags to generate the content.

Comment: It seems to be happening only on months where the first event is on the first of the month.
http://fryemuseum.org/calendar/newsletter/2014/08/
http://fryemuseum.org/calendar/newsletter/2014/04/
http://fryemuseum.org/calendar/newsletter/2014/03/

Comment: true— does that elucidate anything? seems even weirder.  i've updated my post with another link which uses the same set of rules but does not commit the same first-of-the-month error.

Comment: Are your entries saving correctly. If at all possible could you look at the data in the database? Also are you running the most current version of the cal plugin?